# How to get statistic data from teamcity?

Tags: teamcity-9.0

I'd like to get some statistics data from TeamCity. I don't know if It's better to do this using TeamCity REST API or by queering TeamCity Database to get the data I need.

Can someone advice me which one is better ?
FYI: I tried to use TeamCity Restful web services but if I request a project containing a lot of build configs, I get a timeout exception :

```
iagnostic.web.DiagnosticFilter - Request processing took too long: 192577 ms, request: GET '/app/rest/builds/?locator= ...
```

TeamCity version: 9.1.1(build 37059)

Comment: Can you try to do it from team city dashboard? Will it timeout or not: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/74845422. What data do you need to collect?

Comment: I need to get tests that are red between 2 DateTime, their builds configs and the duration of red.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used REST API. I get failed tests of the last build for each buildConfig.